# Flask Limiter Restrict Acess for a specific user

Tags: python, flask

I am making a flask project where you register and log in and you can make new posts.

```
def ifonly():
    if current_user.role == 'admin':
        return False
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            title1 = request.form['title']
            content2 = request.form['content']
            if len(title1) > 5 and len(title1) < 50 and len(content2) > 5:
                global new
                new = 70
                poster = Post.query.filter_by(name=current_user.name).first()
                if current_user.name == current_user.name:
                    return True
            else:   
                return False
        else:
            return False

@app.route('/makepost/',methods=['POST','GET'])
@limiter.limit(f'8 per 10 minutes',cost=ifonly)
def makepost():
    sear = 1
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/login') 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        content = request.form['content']
        if len(title) < 5:
            flash("Title must be at least 5")
        if len(title) > 50:
            flash("Title must be 50 characters max")
        if  len(content) < 5:
            flash('Content must be at least 5 letters')
        if len(title) > 5 and len(title) < 50 and len(content) > 5:
            sear = 2
        if sear == 2:
            global post1
            post1 = Post(title=title,content=content,name=current_user.name,author=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(post1)
            db.session.commit()
    if sear != 2:
        flash('We couldnt make your post')
    return render_template('posts.html')
```

But if a user made over 8 posts in less than 10 minutes then all users can't make new posts. I want only the user who made over 8 posts to not be able to make new posts. Also, I use flask-limiter. Here is the user and post model:

```
class Users(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    missions = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post',backref='user')

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text,unique=False,nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    author = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'),unique=False)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if current_user.name == current_user.name:` I think your issue is here.

Comment: I removed this line of code but I still have the same error.